# VBA DSum not working in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code set up to sum the amount field in my qryExpenses query.

```
Private Sub Command18_Click()
   Dim txtExpense As Currency
   txtExpense = DSum("Amount", "qryExpenses")    
End Sub
```

For some reason it is not pulling the amount into my form. Am I missing something?

Comment: `txtExpense` is only local to your click handler. If you want the value of txtExpense to show up some where you have to assign it to the Value or Text property of a control on your form.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands now, you have declared a variable to hold the total amount, you retrieve the amount with `DSum()` but you do not assign its value to the textbox control. In addition I believe you have given the variable the same name as the Textbox control.

If that's the case, change the variable name to something meaningful and then assign its value to the textbox control.

```
Private Sub Command18_Click()

    Dim totalExpense As Currency
    totalExpense = DSum("Amount", "qryExpenses") 

    Me.txtExpense.Value = totalExpense 
End Sub
```